# PHP preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have this tag into my html file:

```
    {{block:my_test_block}} 
{{news:my_test_block2}}
```

I need to parse and replace this tag with content from db, my aproach:

```
     ob_start();
     require_once('file.php');
     $template = ob_get_contents();
     ob_end_clean();

      $line = preg_replace_callback('/{(\w+)}/' , "parseTag" , $template);

function parseTag($matches){
   //here switch for block, news, 
}
```

is it the right way?
Thanks.

Comment: Define "right way". Does it work? :)

Comment: I need to modify the regualr expression for see if it is a block or news!

Comment: My answer resolve your problem?

Comment: @Ste my answer solve your problem? let us know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use

```
'/{{(.+):(.+)}}/'
```

So in the $matches[1] you will see the block or news.

Your script shall look like that

```
$line = preg_replace_callback('/{{(.+):(.+)}}/' , "parseTag" , $template);

function parseTag($matches){
   if($matches[1] == 'block'){
        $return = 'Its Blocked';
   }elseif($matches[1] == 'news'){
        $return = 'Great news';
   }else{
        $return = 'Ops...';
   }
   return $return;
}
```